# link automatic add a slash(/) itself inlink and destroy my link in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, slash

My link is for another page news.php is :-
`href="news?id=etc"`

Here I remove `.php` after news in href.

I use the below code in my .htaccess file for to remove .php extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and after I click on the link, the URL will be like this after opening of page: 
`http://localhost/themobilesapp/news?id=15`

but it automatically converted into: 
`http://localhost/themobilesapp/news/?id=15`

it adds a slash(/) in the place of `.php` after /news

Please help me to remove this slash(/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^themobilesapp/news\?id\=([^/]*)$ /themobilesapp/news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It will conwert the original URL like:

`http://localhost/themobilesapp/news.php?id=15`
to
`http://localhost/themobilesapp/news?id=15`

But from my point of view it'll look beter like this:

`http://localhost/themobilesapp/news/id/15`

If you like it than use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^themobilesapp/news/id/([^/]*)$ /themobilesapp/news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sir, I tried both RewriteRules suggest by you but they are unable to correct it. Link is still same "http://localhost/themobilesapp/news/?id=15" and now it is also showing me picture directory on this page.

Comment: are you sure that you correct understand the feature of RewriteRules?
url does not change, RewriteRules just help you call one url, while in your browser and in your templates (i mean <a href=''>) is using a pretty one.

Comment: create please a page which will show "Hello world" with url like `http://localhost/themobilesapp/news.php?id=20` after create on your home page a link with <a href='themobilesapp/news/id/20'>link</a> and you should see your "Hello world" message

Comment: try to remove all others revrite rules, leave just mine, they can conflict with each other

Comment: Sir,
    This is my .htaccess file 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^themobilesapp/news/id/([^/]*)$ /themobilesapp/news.php?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /themobilesapp/404error.php

and this is my link on index page :
href="news?id=<?=value 

still slash is coming.. @D.Dimitrioglo

Comment: where is your `themobilesapp` part in your link?